# "Tweet this" button

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, twitter

Sometimes, I ask a question on stack overflow, and then go to Twitter to see if I can get help there. Any developers that follow me are immediately directed to the SO question. I've actually seen a few devs sign up for SO because of this.

The steps I follow are this -

1. Write question on Stack Overflow
2. Shorten the URL for my newly posted question
3. Think of a tweet that is 140 characters - the length of the url
4. Post the tweet

It sure would be nice if there was a "Tweet this question" button on SO. Maybe I would push it, and then a tweet would be auto-populated for me using the tags - maybe one that says "Help me with this (tag1, tag2, tag3) question on stackoverflow" and then a shortened URL.

Although some of the answers already added are wary of a million "share" buttons being added, I don't think very many people use those sites as they use twitter. In a lot of ways it's as much a question answering service as SO is, and as I described above it's helped me find answers to programming questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3926

Comment: yadayada **Greasemonkey** yadayada

Comment: Greasemonkey is the jQuery of MetaSO.

Comment: I think this is a great feature request.

More generally, I think that SO should be far more connected to everything -- Twitter, Facebook, etc.  Right now it is an island.

Comment: I can see Jeff spamming my Twitter if he would use that on every question...

Answer (score 9):

Not sure we need ye olde "Share This" button...

[image: Share What Now?]

Something...pure about SO not having a litany of icons at the bottom of each post...

Comment: You said everything I did pretty much in a much shorter way.

Comment: Picture p == new Words[1000];

Comment: Agreed. It is scary how sometimes I am trying to view a blog post or something and my mouse accidentally goes over the "share" icon due site and 3/4ths of the post is hidden by links!

Comment: this makes my face hurt

Answer (score 7):

You may now also shorten the question URL in the form

example.com/q/12345

Comment: Are there plans to register a shorter domain for the se sites?

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten the URL by excluding the title and only including the id.

Example: ["Tweet this" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4773)

As far as a button, I would hope not. I am not a big fan of cluttering the UI with more buttons and mechanisms to use with other websites. I made this point in a previous question concerning submitting stuff to Digg. All those websites that have a jillion buttons to submit their content to a jillion different providers always has annoyed me.

I find Twitter to only be useful for harassing elected officials.

Comment: I didn't realise Lindsey Lohan was elected.

Comment: That's not a shortened URL, it's 44 characters.

Comment: @bpapa: As it is shorter than the URL with the question title it is indeed shortened. However, it is not short. But then no one claimed it was.

Comment: It would be nice if the URL was shorter still -- Flickr's shrink down to the fixed size: http://flic.kr/p/6E3Ve4 (for example) - so "questions" *could* be shrunk to "q" to give space for an extra 8 chars

Answer (score 3):

**Firefox Users...**

[Integrate a "Tweet this" button with Greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/community-challenge-integrate-a-tweet-this-button-with-greasemonkey)

[image]

Comment: Do these work in Safari or Chrome? Or... wait for it... IE?

Comment: Does greasemonkey work in any of those browsers?

Comment: Nope. This is a FF-only solution.

Comment: Why would you be using another browser?

Comment: For one reason, if you're an iPhone developer. Which SO seems to have quite a lot of these days. Many of them may be using Safari. Like me. Hey let's get into a BROWSER WAR debate though, those are fun.

Comment: REAL PROGRAMMERS USE LYNX !!!!1111!!!!!