# Add a 'Tweet this question' link for the OP

Tags: feature-request, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tweet question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3926)
>   [“Tweet this” button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/tweet-this-button)
>   [Integrate a “Tweet this” button with Greasemonkey.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3957)

Whenever I ask a question, I end up tweeting it to expose it to the people that follow me on twitter, many of which are SO users and in the same field. It would be nice to have a "Tweet this question" link after creating a question to automate the process.

Comment: Dupe-tastic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4773 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3926

Comment: Oh, and also, a bountied one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3957

Comment: Looks like the bounty is ending in 2 minutes, so it's too late to go for it...

Comment: I pray to a multitude of fictitious deities that this never actually gets implemented into the system. Twitter is a disease and I hope it remains just with those poor souls who greasemonkey up a solution.

Comment: Wow, I'm lazy. Should have searched. Thanks guys.

Comment: TheTXI: If you think Twitter is a disease, you either don't understand it or are "doing it wrong". I know this sounds like a snooty Twitter-whore comeback, but I think you're completely wrong.

Comment: John: 99% of the twittering world is "doing it wrong" then.

Answer (score 0):

...or, [Integrate a "Tweet this" button with Greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3957/integrate-a-tweet-this-button-with-greasemonkey)

Answer (score 0):

This has been sought before...  There is a grease monkey script out there, but it is not perfect...

[Tweet question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3926/tweet-question-and-answer)